# Uncaught TypeError: Object #article has no method 'load'

Tags: jquery

I am populating a select box based on the selection of another select box, but I am getting the following error when I look at the google chrome console:

Uncaught TypeError: Object #article has no method 'load'

Here is the html/script:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Populating Select Boxes</h1>
<form action="select-boxes.html">
<label for="category">Category:</label>
<select name="category" id="category">
<option value="easy">Easy</option>
<option value="medium">Medium</option>
<option value="hard">Hard</option>
</select>
<input type="submit" value="next &raquo;"/>
<select name="article" id="article"></select>
</form>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.5.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$('form').submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var categoryName = $('#category').val();

    ('#article').load('select-boxes-' + categoryName + '.html');

});

});
</script>
</body>
```

Here is an example of select-boxes-easy.html that gets loaded if easy is selected:

```
<option value="easy1">Easy 1</option>
<option value="easy2">Easy 2</option>
<option value="easy3">Easy 3</option>
<option value="easy4">Easy 4</option>
<option value="easy5">Easy 5</option>
<option value="easy6">Easy 6</option>
```

After adding the $, I now get the following error when selecting a category and then clicking next:

XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/xaisoft/Desktop/javascripting/PopulateSelectBoxes/select-boxes-easy.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: missing a `$` in your `('#article')`.

Comment: Without wanting to sound rude, next time, triple check your code before asking such a question here ;)

Comment: @Felix, I understand, I was looking at it and staring and I just missed the dollar sign.  Similar to probably missing a semi-colon. Forgive me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You forgot the dollar:

```
$('#article').load(...);
```

Comment: Wow, thanks, I knew it had to be something that simple because I was actually following along a video that Remy Sharp created, but now when I click next, I get another error message: XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///C:/Users/xaisoft/Desktop/javascripting/PopulateSelectBoxes/select-boxes-easy.html. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.